# Preserve the url for subpage

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a units page

```
abc.com/units
```

When I visit

```
abc.com/units/toronto
```

this shows a 404 page.

I want to preserve the url /units/* and basically just redirect to units page while maintaining the url

So, if I visit

`abc.com/units/scarborough`

I want to maintain this url but just show the units page.
Is this possible without having to touch .htaccess file? Why is it so hard to implement such a basic feature.